# How to insert image to mongodb via SimpleSchema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, simple-schema

How can I define a SimpleSchema template to store image data/binary data inside a mongodb storage.

What is the type I should use? Should I use Object type?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Buffer type to store image.

But there is size limit of 16 MB for BSON-document so [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) may help you to store files larger than 16 MB.

Answer (score 0):

It's not always a good idea to store images or other files in `MongoDB` database(or any other database). Rather store them in a separate Storage server like `AWS S3` or `Azure blob storage` or whatever storage server and keep the link to the file in your `MongoDB` database. It will help you keep the DB server lean.

For more details study on `multi-tier application architecture`.